# How to get a response in a http get query in TCL

Tags: tcl

There is a small code that should send a request to the site and receive a reply. I only understand the language and do not understand how to do it.
Here is the piece of code that sends the request using the http get method.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set id [open file.txt w]
set tok [::http::geturl "https://example.com/reques.php?=somedate -timeout 2000 -channel $id]
::http::cleanup $tok
close $id
set id [open file.txt]
set phone [read $id]
close $id
puts $phone
```

But when executing the code, I get an error

```
invalid command name "http::geturl"
    while executing
```

Answer (score 2):

The http package needs to be loaded into your Tcl interpreter; it's not there by default. Thus, at the top of your script (just below the `#!` line) put:

```
package require http
```

Indeed, it's usually a good idea to state every package that you depend on that way, as it makes it easy to see everything that is going on (and you can optionally state what versions you expect):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# At least Tcl 8.5; 8.6 will be fine too
package require Tcl 8.5

# Any version of Expect
package require Expect

# Any version of the http package that supports the v2 API
package require http 2
```

Package names are case-sensitive. And you can

Comment: Many thanks, Donal! Now I will know more about the TCL language.
I tried to do as you wrote, and I get the text of the page in the format html, and I send the request in the format of the get and wait for a response from the site with certain data, which I then have to interpret. If I send a get request through curl bash script to me the data comes from the site, how can I do the same in Tcl? Now I get an error 301 in the body of the page, maybe because it's a site on https?

Comment: I tried to use your example for another user for https and I get an error "can't find package tls"

Comment: The `tls` package (which is the SSL support required for encrypting the communications) is available elsewhere, but that's into the realm of a separate Question here. Also, I suspect it's one that must've been answered before.

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem without it, I found an api that uses http. But still thanks a lot, your answer allowed me to figure out the structure of the code...

Answer (score 0):

I used following command for TCL in Naviserver.
I don't if it helps but this is what that worked for me in AJAX call.

```
ns_return 200 application/json $your_response_content
```

Syntax: `ns_return ?-binary? status mime-type body`

Reference: [Naviserver Commands for TCL](https://naviserver.sourceforge.io/n/naviserver/files/ns_return.html)